# Stop page load and redirect in a content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a extension in Chrome and need to stop a page load (without loading the page completely) and redirect to a url if matches from ajax query.

I am using `content_scripts`.

And tried to use

```
 window.location.replace("http://facebook.com");
```

But the redirect occurs once the page load is completed..

Even tried to use

```
window.stop();
```

this is also not working to stop page loading.

Is there any possible way to stop a page load and redirect it before page load?

Comment: Why `window.stop()` is not working?

Comment: @void It's firing too late. I'm writing an answer right now.

Comment: It start very late and I see the website data, then it redirect

Comment: @Xan Right now I am trying to use pure js. .do not know should I use chrome predefined variable for same. Do you have any idea for it?

Comment: I edited your question for you (like you said, you're doing pure JS - what does jQuery have to do with anything?) and removed anything not having to do with the actual question. I recommend you reading through the site [tour] and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide for future questions. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Yes will read it.. New here so forgive me. :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying this with a content script.

Content scripts have a [`run_at` parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at), which indicates when (relative to page loading) they execute.

By default, content scripts run at `document_idle` level: Chrome waits until the page has completely loaded before executing it.

You have two options:

- You can keep the content script route, but you need to indicate `"run_at" : "document_start"` parameter in the content script configuration.

  This will execute your code as soon as possible (before the document is loaded, but after the response is started).
- If you're concerned about not loading the page at all (not sending a request to the site), you need to intercept it at a lower level. [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) can provide the means to do that.

  If you catch the request at `onBeforeRequest` event, you can redirect it before it is even sent. Filtering by type is recommended. Note that you won't even need a content script in this case: `webRequest` events need to be listened to in a background script.

  See the [CatBlock example](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#catblock).

Comment: also, I need to do it before even sending the request to website. .
so will onBeforeRequest work in content_scripts? I checked that many code do not work in content_scripts, I will try it now.

Comment: No, it will not. Like I said, look at the CatBlock example and modify it for your needs.

Comment: Getting error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onBeforeRequest' of undefined

Comment: Permissions, permissions.. Anyway, this is not a good topic to discuss in comments. I will not answer further here.

Comment: Permission getting error "The 'webRequest' API cannot be used with event pages."

Comment: Don't know if you reply..
I am trying to send a xhr request to a domain like catblock example.. But the xhr did not stop, i am getting the reply from domain continuously.. can you tell me is this possible to stop it?