# open a chrome tab from content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to open a chrome tab using content script.
I checked message passing in chrome example and tried this
**In content script:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function (response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

And in background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
            chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log('resp.type');
            console.log(sender.tab ?
                    "from a content script:" + sender.tab.url :
                    "from the extension");
            if (request.greeting == "hello") {
                chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://google.com'});
                sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
            }
        });
```

It is working well, the problem is that the tab is opening but also lots of tabs get opened...What I need to do to open just one tab?

Comment: How is your content script injected? Add the relevant manifest rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the content script it also runs in the new tab that you opened so it ends up opening an infinite amount of tabs. To limit this, you can put the `tabs.create` inside of a function that doesn't run immediately on page load.

Comment: No it is still opening.. Now it start opening from tab position 0 rather than the next tab previously..

Comment: I figured it out. Give me a second to update the answer.

Comment: @AR7: you don't have to leave your old content struck out, as SO provides full edit history if someone cares to look.

Comment: I mean, sometimes it _does_ make sense to leave content struck out, but probably only for the cases when a popular correct answer becomes obsolete.

Comment: @Xan can you check this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527149/stop-page-load-and-redirect-in-a-content-script/28527224?noredirect=1#comment45370230_28527224
 need to know if I can let the background script run only one time..

Comment: @kannu You don't take hints, do you? No, I will not answer _new questions_ in _comments_. Make a new question.

Comment: I tried a lot and tried to look in the chrome but unable to get if I can stop multiple request.. but I am not able to find anything regarding that.. I am new to chrome extension and playing with it.. so that issue is that..yea can make new question

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28645981/stop-multiple-xhr-request-in-background-script @Xan

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you are calling the "chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener" multiple times, so when it does get a message, all the listeners you added are opening a tab, once for each one that was setup.